# Global variable initialization issue

Tags: php, drupal-7

I've a Drupal file (mymodule.module) which contains something like(actual code is very long):

```
$test =1;

//hook_user_login
function mymodule_user_login()
{
global $test;
print "$test";
}
```

But when this hook function "mymodule_user_login" is called by Drupal on user login  --  $test's value is found to be null.

What could be the reason?

I've tried Googling but could not find useful answer.

Comment: need to define global outside function also

Comment: Scope of your code is not global.

Comment: @zerkms i have tried same :) any wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way this could not work is if the file is included inside a function. E.g., your code is in `foo.php`, and is executed as:

```
function drupal_bar() {
    include 'foo.php';
}
```

Then `$test` would not be in the `global` scope, hence the function cannot get it from there either. I don't know Drupal, but it seems likely that this would be the case.

The real solution is not to use the `global` scope, precisely because of this and because global state soon devolves into madness.

<sub>The localised solution for this particular case is to also write `global $test` before `$test = 1` to explicitly declare the variable in the global scope, wherever it may be included from later.</sub>

Comment: I'm in same problem again.. and adding global $test; in the global arena is making it work! As in Mic1780's answer. Is that what you've said in the last para?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Before using global variable you have to declare it.

```
global $abc;
$abc = 'value';

function mymodule_user_login(){
    global $abc;
    echo $abc;
}
mymodule_user_login();
```

//output : value;

Answer (score 0):

One reason why `$test` is probably empty is because it may have been overwritten. So you can trace your code from where `$test` was defined through all includes and required pages to see if `$test` was reset to another value including all functions that references the object using the `global` keyword.

Alternately beside using the `global` keyword you, can get global variables using the super global associate array `$GLOBALS`.

```
$test = 1;

function mymodule_user_login() {
   print $GLOBALS['test'];
   // print "Just a string $GLOBALS[test]";
}
```

Here is the link to the php.net article on variable scope for better information:
[PHP: Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the global variable first, as global. Better to declare in hook init function.

```
// initialization function hook

function mymodule_init() {
    global $test; // declare the global variable in init function
    $test = "Hi";

}
```

Now the global variable will be available in your function

```
// your function below
//hook_user_login
function mymodule_user_login()
{
     global $test;
     print "$test";
}
```

After that you can access the global variable in any module.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience writing wordpress plugins (which I would assume have somewhat similar ways to clean up variables) I know that you must add the variable to a global scope before declaring it. He is an example:

```
global $test;
$test =1;

//hook_user_login
function mymodule_user_login()
{
global $test;
print "$test";
}
```

Notice how `$test` is declared as a global both outside the function and before use inside the module function.

Answer (score 0):

As all the other answers have stated you need to set the scope of that variable.

If you check out the index.php file within the root of your Drupal install you will notice that nearly everything processed by the script happens within another function, meaning **very few variables are in the global scope**. Nearly all of which is started from within drupal_bootstrap().

I would have just commented on another answer but don't have the reputation to do this.

This will do it though:

```
global $test;
$test =1;

//hook_user_login
function mymodule_user_login()
{
global $test;
print "$test";
}
```

Comment: This is literally my exact answer.

Comment: I know it was similar to the others, I wanted to comment with the reason specific to drupal but don't have comment privileges.

Comment: Gotcha. Didnt try to call you out and sound like a douche

Answer (score 0):

placing the keyword **GLOBAL** in front of the variable that should be recognized as global.

```
<?php
// declare test as global variable (get from global scope)
global $test;

// set global variable test
$test = 1;

function mymodule_user_login()
{
    // declare test as global variable (get from global scope)
    global $test;

    // print global variable test
    print "$test";
}

mymodule_user_login();
```

output

```
1
```

---

alternative use $GLOBALS

```
<?php
// set global variable test
$test = 1;

function mymodule_user_login()
{
    // print global variable test
    print $GLOBALS['test'];
}

mymodule_user_login();
```

output

```
1
```

for more info, read [variables scope documentation](http://php.net/manual/it/language.variables.scope.php)

P.S. [Global Variables Are Bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)